# ¿Cómo EVITO el cambio de URL al llamar a un método en CODEIGNITER?

Tags: php, codeigniter

mi situación es la siguiente:
Quisiera evitar que se cambie el nombre de una ruta, ejemplo:

```
localhost/proyecto/registro
```

al presionar un botón como lo es "ENVIAR", al actulizarse la página se cambie la ruta por:

```
localhost/proyecto/insertar
```

Ya que cuando realizo la inserción de un nuevo registro, me carga de nuevo la vista con un mensaje diciendo "usuario agregado", pero me cambiar la URL también y quisiera que quedara como antes, gracias.

La pregunta puede ser algo noob, disculpenme es que comenze hace relativamente poco a utilizar este frame..

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow Césc! Te invito a que coloque el código asociado a la descripción de tu pregunta, de esta forma nos facilitas el poder colaborarte a solucionar tu duda. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ocurre porque en tu controlador lo mas seguro es que tengas que al final te cargue la vista:

Por ejemplo estas en:

http://localhost/Farmacia/

y le das al boton agregar, te cambiara la url y te iras a algo como:
http://localhost/Farmacia/producto/frm_alta

Ahi dentro tendras tu formulario para rellenar, lo rellenas y supongamos que el form envia a:

http://localhost/Farmacia/producto/agregar

y que pasa? lo mas seguro es que al final de tu metodo agregar tengas algo como 
$this->index();

que te carga la vista del listado de productos, pero como lo mandas a llamar con 
$this->index();

Te carga el metodo y con ello las vistas y todo lo demas, pero la url seguira diciendo
http://localhost/Farmacia/producto/agregar   (En tu caso dice INSERTAR)

y diras... ok y como lo soluciono? pues muy facil, en lugar de mandar a llamar a la funcion con un codigo php, mandala a traer con la url, que significa esto? pues facil... que hagas un REDIREC

------------------TEORIA----------------------

redirect('ruta');

redirect('si escribes el nombre del controlador, este te cargara el index del controlador');

redirect('si quieres que se mande a llamar una funcion de tu controlador entonces usas nombrecontrolador/funcion');

------------------/FIN TEORIA----------------------

seguimos con el ejemplo, yo quiero que al terminar de agregar un producto me mande al listado de productos el cual esta en el index de mi controlador
pero si hago un $this->index(); me cargara la vista porque ejecutara la funcion que carga la vista PERO mi url seguira igual, entonces haces un redirect, que te envia a un lugar con base en la url y como la url se encarga de llamar al controlador y los metodos, matas dos pajaros de un tiro

Entonces

**redirect('producto');**

va a llevarte a la url
http://localhost/Farmacia/producto

y la url va a llevarte al index del controlador, el cual es "producto" y como el index carga las vistas con eso tengo :)

**NOTA:** En tu caso como veo que estas usando el controlador default, puedes hacer un:

**redirect('');**

en tu caso esto te enviaria a:
localhost/proyecto/

pero si quieres que te envie al inicial que era
localhost/proyecto/registro

basta con un redirect que apunte a esa funcion, asi:
**redirect('nombrecontroladordefaul/registro');**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la llamada a localhost/proyecto/insertar por AJAX y así te quedas en localhost/proyecto/registro

Comment: Tu respuesta fue reportada como de baja calidad. por favor mira [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cargar el envío del formulario en el mismo controlador donde muestras la vista del form.

```
if($this->input->post()){
   //validacion del form
}else{
   //cargar la vista
}
```